# ReactNative viewport change with GoogleMaps geolocation search

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native

I'm using ReactNative with the GoogleMaps API (by Airbnb). I implemented the GoogleMaps geolocation search, and am receiving a lat/long response back as json.

Now I'm having trouble re-rendering the map to display at the searched lat/long.

So far to fix this I have tried:

- Changing the state of the region attribute of MapView
- Changing the state of the initialRegion attribute of MapView
- Different combinations of onChange and region, none of which have worked.

Would appreciate hearing suggestions of what to try next - you can find my complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/ginnyfahs/0b4d9780e559d632614ffbb1e3bfac9a).

Answer (score 1):

you can change your code to be like this

```
render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}> // add a container view with absolute position same as map
   <MapView
    provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
    style={styles.container}
    region={this.state.locationCoordinates} // change from initialRegion to region
    zoomEnabled={true}
    scrollEnabled={true}
    >
      <MapView.Marker
      coordinate={{
        latitude: 37.7749,
        longitude: -122.4194,
      }}
    />
    </MapView>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}> // remove input container from inside the MapView
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Where to?"
        style={ styles.input }
        onChangeText={this.handleLocationInput}
        value={this.state.locationInput}
        onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: When I change to initialRegion, I'm able to jump to new search locations - but I lose the ability to scroll on the map (even though I have a scrollEnabled prop set to true). Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: what is happen dose it not move at all or what also you should use region not initialRegion

Comment: note that your code has initialRegion and the answer has just region